# Using an epson DS-40 scanner on linux

Tags: drivers, usb, 15.10, scanner

I just got a little epson scanner [(DS-40)](http://www.epson.com.au/products/scanner/workforce_ds-40.asp) and I have been having problems getting it working.

I installed the drivers from [this page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=43316&DSCCHK=86614f07e71ba1e0e0c7d7da959dce051fb3c889) and the device powers on and shows up under `lsusb`

> Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04b8:0152 Seiko Epson Corp.

The driver installer script installed these packages

> graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick++11 libgraphicsmagick3

But I cant work out how I actually scan with it. When I put paper in it it grabs on to it but doesn't scan. Running `scanimage -L` returns

```
device `epsonds:libusb:001:013' is a Epson DS-40 ESC/I-2
device `imagescan:usb:esci:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13:1.0' is a EPSON Epson_DS-40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the drivers from the website running the command `imagescan` starts up a GUI which lets you pick the scan options and scan the document.